# Clojure REPL Import trouble-shooting

Tags: clojure

Okay. I'm trying to muck about with `twitter4j` inside a Clojure REPL, provided by Leiningen. I've specified `twitter4j` as a build dependency:

```
(defproject testproject "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Tryin stuff"
  :repositories {
                 "twitter4j" "http://twitter4j.org/maven2"
                 }
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]
                 [org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core "3.0.5"]
                 [org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream "3.0.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.8"]]
  :ring {:handler testproject.core/app}
  :profiles {:dev
             {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

So far, so good. `lein deps` downloads everything without complaint into the default repo in `~/.m2`. Awesome. I fire up the REPL, and I get this and only this:

```
user=> (import '(org.twitter4j.conf ConfigurationBuilder))

ClassNotFoundException org.twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

The `twitter4j` jars are all present and accounted for, in `~/.m2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/3.0.5/`. Is there... something I don't get about importing Java classes? Some extra config I need to provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (the proper package name):

```
user=> (import '(twitter4j.conf ConfigurationBuilder))
```

Comment: Okay, actual question: is it standard in Clojure to be able to drop the 'com/org' from a package address? In Java/Scala I'd use org.twitter4j.whathaveyou -- not so in Clojure?

Comment: Given that twitter4j is a Java (not Clojure) library, I'd say this is not limited to Clojure.  I've seen projects both ways (with and without the reverse domain prefix) for Clojure.

Comment: org/com prefix is just a convention hence some follow it and some dont :)